# Three level panel menu using Javascript, Can't get content to load properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, navigation

I've got a small problem with the navigation framework I'm trying to implement on my site. Coded as follows:

HTML

```
<div class="panel1">
    first navigation ul li set
</div>
<div class="panel2" id="subnav">
    AJAX loaded navigation ul li set
</div>
<div class="panel3" id="content">
    content loaded by AJAX
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.ajax-link-top').click( function( event ) {
        set_ajax_link( $(this), event );
    });
});

function set_ajax_link( el, event ){
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = el.attr("href");
    load_menu_content( url );
}

function load_menu_content( url ){
    $("#subnav").load( url, { 'ajax': 'true' }, function(){
        $('#subnav a.ajax-link').click( function( event ) {
            set_ajax_link_sub( $(this), event );
        });
    });
}

function set_ajax_link( el, event ){
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = el.attr("href");
    load_page_content( url );
}

function load_page_content( url ){
    $("#content").load( url, { 'ajax': 'true' }, function(){
        $('#content a.ajax-link').click( function( event ) {
            set_ajax_link_sub( $(this), event );
        });
    });
}
```

The fix is as follows:

HTML: same
Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var panel2 = $(".panel2");
    var panel3 = $(".panel3");

    $(".panel1").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var url = e.target.href;
        $(".panel2").load(url);
    });

    $(".panel2").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var url_2 = e.target.href;
        panel3.load(url_2);
        });
});
```

The goal is to get links of the class ajax-link-top to load a subnav menu in the #subnav div, and to get links of the ajax-link class to load page content into the #content div, from either the top nav panel or the subnav panel.

The result I'm getting right now is that anytime any of the links are clicked, they load the content, menu or otherwise, into the #content div. I'm sure I just have something off in my JS code somewhere, but I can't see it.

Any and all help appreciated!
M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes you're using jQuery.

I would take a somewhat different approach, instead of tying event handlers to each individual link you can target the panel div's themselves - the click events will bubble up.  It'll save you a lot of repetitive binding.  You should add check to make sure what was clicked on in the container was actually a link if there are more elements than just a series of links in the containers otherwise you'll get spurious events if non-link elements are clicked.  This way you're only binding two events.

I've added a faked out load to simulate the AJAX load to illustrate.  There's a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/WFb8a/.

HTML

```
<div class="panel1">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="subnav1" href="#link1">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a id="subnav2" href="#link2">Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>        
</div>
<div class="panel2" id="subnav">
    AJAX loaded navigation ul li set
</div>
<div class="panel3" id="content">
    content loaded by AJAX
</div>

<script id="subnav1-content">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="subnav1-link1" href="#link1">Subnav1 Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a id="subnav1-link2" href="#link2">Subnav1 Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>        
</script>

<script id="subnav2-content">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="subnav2-link1" href="#link1">Subnav2 Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a id="subnav2-link2" href="#link2">Subnav2 Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>        
</script>

<script id="subnav1-link1-content">
    <h1>Content 1</h1>
</script>

<script id="subnav1-link2-content">
    <h1>Content 2</h1>
</script>

<script id="subnav2-link1-content">
    <h1>Content 3</h1>
</script>

<script id="subnav2-link2-content">
    <h1>Content 4</h1>
</script>​
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $panel2 = $(".panel2");
    var $panel3 = $(".panel3");

    $(".panel1").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        $panel2.html($("#" + e.target.id + "-content").html());
    });

    $(".panel2").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        $panel3.html($("#" + e.target.id + "-content").html());
    });
});​
```

Comment: This seems really clean, and thanks for the fast response. But would it be true to say that I can use this solution with the $panel2.html(...); using the url for the file I want to load? I apologize for my rudimentary understanding of AJAX and JS. I'm a bit new to this.

Comment: Yeah you should be able to replace the $panel2.html and $panel3.html lines with $panel2.load(e.target.href) and have actual content jax'ed into your divs.

Comment: well that's strange. Now my links are just acting as standard links and reloading the page. Your code is working well in the fiddle though, so not sure what's causing the issue.

Comment: Sounds like the event click event isn't binding, either the jQuery selector is wrong in your code or you're getting a JS error that's preventing the event from binding.  Another possibility is that you haven't included the e.preventDefault() to stop the default action from firing.

Comment: Yep, typo on the preventDefault(). with those $panel2.loads, do I need to specify ajax: true? currently getting no response from my top level links at the moment. Indeed, the JS is throwing an error of "uncaught TypeError". I'll look into it.

Comment: I removed the e.stopPropagation(); and it seems to work fine now. Thank you so much! I'll revise my original post to include the code for the fix.

Comment: Hrm... what version of jQuery are you loading?  You might want to add a line above `var $panel` - `var $ = jQuery;`.  That will make sure jQuery is what's been used as $ and will only effect the scope within that block so it shouldn't mess up anything else if prototype or something else is also loading.  stopPropagation has been a part of the jQuery event for as long as I can remember so something else may be bound to $.  The `{type: 'ajax'}` param would be getting passed as data to the server, so if your server needs that then you'd want to add that back in.

Comment: Using version 1.7.2 from the code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js source. I'll double check, but everything seems to be working as is.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would handle that.

First off, I would use event delegation so I don't have to worry about binding events when I load stuff:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "a.js-load-subnav", function (ev) {
        $("#subnav").load($(this).attr("href"), {ajax: "true"});
        return false;
    });
    $(document).on("click", "a.js-load-content", function (ev) {
        $("#content").load($(this).attr("href"), {ajax: "true"});
        return false;
    });
});
```

Then, I would set the HTML of my nav and subnav appropriately so that the links use either the `js-load-subnav` class or the `js-load-content` class. (I use `js-` to show that these links are just for JavaScript's use, and are not useful for styling the links.)